# c++ special member copy constructor

Tags: c++

I have understood the concept of copy constructors that we make a pointer has a different  locations and pointing to the same value.

But I wonder why when I try to access a value for a variable of an object its value is different than the value of the other one.

For example:

```
#include <iostream.h>
using namespace std;

class myclass {
public:
    int a, b;
    string c;
};

int main()
{
    myclass foo, bar;
    foo = bar;
    bar.a = 20;
    cout << foo.a << endl;  // why it is not printing 20 here, as implicit copy
                            // constructor copy all members from object bar
                            // to object foo?
}
```

Comment: Because you copied before setting that member.

Comment: *"i have understood the concept of copy constructors"*, No, you didn't :(

Comment: You'll only get pointers pointing to the same object when you have pointers. There are no pointers here, just two separate objects. Changing one object won't change the other.

Comment: You actually used the assignment operator here and not the copy constructor (though the result would be the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The copy constructor is not passing a reference or pointer of `a`to the new object, it is copying the value of this **primitive integer**. To achieve your desired result (which by your example I'm assuming is to assign the value of `a` after copying your object), you should restructure your class to have `a` be a **pointer** to an integer. Consider the following example:

```
class myclass
{
    int *a, *b;
    string c;
    myclass()
    {
        a = new int;
        b = new int;
    }
};

int main()
{
    myclass foo, bar;
    foo = bar;
    *bar.a = 20;
    cout << foo.a << endl;
}
```

This will cause the address that will contain "20" to be passed during copy construction. Now when `a` is properly set, it will be reflected in both objects.
This answer comes with the disclaimer, that I would not consider this to be best practice, and ultimately I encourage you to reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

> why is here not printing 20 as implicit copy constructpr copy all       members from object bar to object foo ?/

Those *members* have copy constructors and assignment operators overloaded (or built-in) as well, when you do the assignment:

```
foo=bar;
```

then all members from `bar` are copy-assigned to corresponding fields in `foo`, and neither `int` nor `std::string` have any relation with the instances they were initialized from. Also please note that here you are not invoking any copy-constuctor, rather overloaded assignment operators (`operator=`).